# Unity help - rotations not working :(

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

Okay so I am working on a platformer in unity 2D. I have some animations for a character with a player controller attached (punch, kick and block, which work fine). When I move, my player controller calculates his velocity and depending on its value, if he is not jumping or blocking/kicking/punching he will be in the 'walk' or 'run' states (if not idle). Basically this just means his limbs rotate at a certain speed (the limbs are children of the player, who is a parent).

However, this simple task is turning out to be hard. I originally had the following script to make the limbs rotate:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotation : MonoBehaviour {

 private int b;

 void FixedUpdate () {
     b = PlayerController.b;
     float y = transform.localEulerAngles.z;
     transform.RotateAround (transform.position, Vector3.forward, 
b*45*Mathf.Sin(3*Time.fixedTime)-y);
 }
}
```

(Ignore the 'b').

This worked fine until I turned the character to the left, when the rotations started going haywire.

I decided to simplify and use the following script to rotate.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotation : MonoBehaviour {

float y;

void Start(){
    y = transform.localRotation.z;
    Debug.Log (y);
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    float u = y + 45 * Mathf.Sin (3 * Time.fixedTime);
    Quaternion rot = transform.localRotation;
    rot.z = u;
    Debug.Log (u);
    transform.localRotation = rot;
    }
}
```

How can this go wrong? This is not even rotating at all. I have tried debugging the angle and have noticed that the angle (of the limb I am looking at) changes for a few seconds (even though I can't see any rotation), then gets stuck at a certain value (usually about 45). What is happening? Am I missing something?

tl;dr I just want to have his limbs oscillate with time.

Comment: I think this simple task is turning out to be hard because you are going a complicated way about it. Have you considered using the Animator component? You could trigger different speeds of the same animation using much more flexible and readable code. Also you can set modifiers for speed of the animation to get exact control of the speed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not sure you understand the issue. The speed is not the problem - part of my player controller measures his horizontal speed and depending on its value puts him either in the 'walk' or 'run' state (if not in any other animation), which just play the same animation at different speeds. The problem is the animation itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think its best you make an animation for walking, and the way you can play it is you can have a variable like `bool isWalking`, and then you say
`if(isWalking){ animator.play(walkAnimation); }`

As you can see there is a variable called 'animator' in mine. You should search up tutorials about the unity animator, those are very helpful. Hopefully this helps, if it does not I'm so sorry